# Fish completion that depends on other flags

Tags: shell, autocomplete, fish

I have a command, that can connect to remote machines and so the completion should be based on which machine the user provided. That means that if the user pass `-D DEVICE_ID` I want the completion to provide items for that specific machine.

I couldn't find a way to access the existing arguments in the argument function. For example I have a completion like so:

```
 complete --command xxx --force-files --arguments "(__fish_complete_pids) (get_process_names)"
```

And I would like the get_process_names to get the processes from the correct machine using the provided flags.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by parsing the command line text to find tokens of interest. The `commandline` builtin has a convenience to walk the tokens of the current process (so we won't pick up -D tokens in other parts of the pipeline).

Here's an example which offers completions for previous tokens. If you complete `example -D alpha -D beta` it will offer "ALPHA" and "BETA" as completions:

```
function example_completer
    # Tokenize the current process, up to the cursor.
    # Find the indices of the "-D" tokens.
    # Offer the next tokens as completions (but uppercase).
    # -o means tokenize, -p means current process only, -c means stop at cursor.
    set tokens (commandline -opc)
    for idx in (seq (count $tokens))
        if test $tokens[$idx] = '-D'
            set next_idx (math $idx + 1)
            string upper -- $tokens[$next_idx]          
        end
    end
end

complete -c example --no-files --arguments '(example_completer)'
```

From this you should be able to find the DEVICE_ID and query from the corresponding machine.